# Cannot create a Powershell script with both Invoke-SqlCmd and Invoke-RestMethod?

Tags: rest, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, sqlcmd

Powershell v3 adds Invoke-WebRequest and Invoke-RestMethod, but I cannot get Invoke-SqlCmd to work from that version. If I drop back to Powershell v2, I can Invoke-SqlCmd, but now Invoke-WebRequest and Invoke-RestMethod are no longer available.

I could 'Invoke-Expression sqlcmd' or '& sqlcmd' but then I think I have to manually marshal the output - which is just a string - to something more objectified for PS.

Is there any way to have all of these methods at once, preferably from PS3?

Comment: Are you explicitly adding the SQL Server Cmdlet Snapin in v3? Maybe something in your profile(s)?

Comment: Try Get-PSSnapin -Registered.  Do you see the snapin listed as available?  If so, try adding it with Add-PSSnapin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found no direct answer to my question, just a work-around.

Installing Powershell 4 and using installutil again to register the .dll files for the Sql Powershell Snapin seems to have worked. No matter what I did with installutil when running PS 3, it always registered the snapin in for version 2 of Powershell, which would not work.

`Get-PSSnapin -Registered` would always show the SQL*100 dlls correctly registered, but for version 2 of Powershell. Repeating the same command for the same dlls when running version 4 would register them for version 4. From there, I could run `Add-PSSnapin Sql*100` and `Invoke-SqlCmd` would then be available.

Although this helped me, it is likely to be something environmental that has gone awry and this answer is probably not going to help anyone much.

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke-SqlCmd` really does exactly that, it executes the external `sclcmd` with the given arguments.

Alternative:

```
Import-Module SQLPS
# Create connection to server using Integrated Security
$ServerName = "localhost"
$DBname = "master"

$sqlConn = New-Object -Type:Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection -ArgumentList:$ServerName
$server = New-Object -Type:Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList:$sqlConn
$Database = $server.Databases[$DBname]

# Get script from file:
#$Script = (Get-Content $ScriptFileName) -Join [Environment]::NewLine
$Script = "sp_who"
$Batch = New-Object -TypeName:Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
$Batch.AddRange($Script)
$result = $Database.ExecuteWithResults($Batch)

$result.Tables | Format-Table
```

Comment: Thanks, the `Format-Table` pipe looks like the bit I was missing when wanting to parse the text output to something more objectified.